# UITextField and/or UIPickerView appearance doesn't always work

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a range of `UITextField` where some have a `UIPickerView` as their `inputAccessoryView`. I globally set the style to be dark, like so:

```
UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
```

Which simply makes the dark theme of `UIKeyboardAppearance` and it works great. But sometimes when the `inputAccessoryView` is a `UIPickerView`the picker is suddenly using the `UIKeyboardApperance.Light` and I can't for life of me understand why. I do not set the `UIKeyboardApperance` anywhere but in my global file, and certainly not to `.Light`. Yet *sometimes* the `UIPickerView` is `.Light`. Most of the time it's `.Dark` like I want, but occasionally it simply switches to the lighter one. The appearance is also set to `.Dark` in the `UIStoryboard` for the `UITextField`.

Does anyone have the faintest idea on why that is?

### Edit

I use `UIImagePicker` to select images from device library in the app, but in this particular case the `UIViewController` that has the `UIImagePicker` control is never entered when the issue I have occurs. Also if I get the issue and then go back (pressing back button for my `UINavigationController`) and then forward again to the `UIViewController` with my `UIPickerView` it will no longer be light, but dark.

Comment: Are you using any native ViewControllers provided by iOS like image picker, camera etc?

Comment: They are implemented yes, but not used when this error occurs. The viewcontroller Image Picker lies in isn't even instantiated when I this error occurs.

Comment: Can you share your code so one can debug as this needs to be checked in xcode

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but unfortunately the project is quite massive and under NDA so I can't share anything :/

Comment: I can understand that but you can make one using handful of classes so it will be easy for you as well to check starnge behaviour

Comment: Well that's the thing, the issue only happens occasionally. I can run the project 10 times without it happening and then I run it an 11th time and suddenly the Picker is white. I've tried what you've suggested and tried to reproduce the issue in a smaller project but I wasn't able to.

Comment: ok then see you can use XCUITest to test this as well it well help you

Comment: it will give you whole bunch of stack trace with screenshot